# Is it at all possible to have a populous, formerly colonial nation in the Indian Ocean?

Tags: internal-consistency, alternate-history, population, colonies

The temperate latitudes of the Indian Ocean and adjacent regions are essentially empty- only the extreme Southwest of Australia and extreme South of Africa dip into the temperate belt.

What if there actually was significant land there in the 40s South?

There are essentially two options:

**I- The "Realistic" Option:**
The Kerguelen LIP (perhaps including the Broken Ridge and Ile de Amsterdam still affixed to the rest of the plateau) is still very volcanically active for some reason, and an area over twice the size of Britain, and perhaps larger than France is above the water from latitudes 43 S to 53 S (parts of the Kerguelen Plateau were subaerial IRL as recently as 20 million years ago).

[image: Kerguelen LIP]

Depicted: the Kerguelen LIP.

**II- Complete ASB Option:**
There is a large continent, possibly the size of India or a bit larger in the same general area, stretching from 40 S down into the 50s S.

**Climate**

The main difference between these options is the climate that they imply (lets assume that there will be no impacts on the rest of the world, or else it is a moot point to discuss whether or not European colonizers could have reached these places).

In the first, "realistic" case, geologically speaking, the land is like Iceland, comprised mostly of basalt and crowned with broad volcanoes that reach as high as 2.75 km. The climate would likely be cool- but warmer than IRL Kerguelen. Still, in the north it would be marine with cool summers and near but likely above freezing winters (this could easily support forests such as those on the South Island and in Valdivia). Further south, of course, temperatures would slowly become cooler until the Southern edge would have a climate like the actual Heard and McDonald islands- tundra/ice.

In the second, its geology is indeterminate as it is not based on the Earth's actual history. Its climate though would be more seasonal and therefore warmer in the summer, though with potential for harsh, continental winters especially in the interior and south. At the far southern edges, the climate would still likely transition to tundra as the land is deeper into Antarctic waters.

In both cases, the climate will likely have ample, frequent rain and be exceptionally cloudy.

**Utility**

Many may be inclined to dismiss settlement on either of these hypothetical landmasses entirely, but that is overly hasty. As the land is larger now, only the coast is scoured by the constant westerly circumpolar winds. Owing to their size, both would be able to support forests in at least a portion of their land (geological expeditions to IRL Kerguelen have revealed that when the plateau was exposed, it was home to forests, as evidenced by fossilized wood). In addition, the fishing and whaling on the west coast of either land mass would likely be some of the best in the world, and again, owing to larger size, increased continentality, and a lower latitude at up to 40/43 S, summer temperatures would generally be warmer than at comparable latitudes in IRL Kerguelen). Also, though this more minor, Kerguelen is home to a species of "cabbage" which is a useful source of Vitamin C.

**Settlement and Main Issue**

So, with the land and climate in mind, is it at all possible that a European colony founded in one of these scenarios could become more populous and therefore, more economically important and powerful than Australia did in our own world? Is it possible that a subaerial Kerguelen LIP could be like a Southern Britian, or a large southern continent perhaps even a 2nd USA or Brazil?

As for who would settle there it is uncertain, but the landmass could be hypothetically discovered as early as the 1520s and would almost certainly have been found and realized to be a large landmass by the 1640s. The Basque or Portuguese, later Dutch settlers, or the British and Irish are all possibilities.

A question sort of implied by this one is why did Australia receive fewer immigrants than the United States? In the latter decades of the 19th Century alone, the US received more immigrants than the entire present day population of Australia.

If this is due to proximity to Europe, then I think an Indian Ocean great power or even regional great power would be out of the question. But if it is due to the lack of Arable land in Australia, maybe there is a chance. Or perhaps there is another factor, social or political that motivated the disparity between the two. This would have a large impact on whether or not these landmasses would have a future beyond seasonal whaling bases or sparsely settled sheep stations.

Thanks for your input

Comment: +1 for the ASB reference!

Answer (score 1):

**Climate isn't the only potential draw card for your new landmass.**

Firstly the larger land mass of option two and the warmer climate at its northern latitudes that come with it would make it a more attractive option for  colonization by one or more European powers than option one would.

Beyond that however even more important would be **mineralogy**. For example one of the early and very important drivers of population growth in early Australia were the gold rushes of the 1860s. So for example lets as a thought experiment say there are two parallel worlds. In one you have your continent option and in the other you have your Kerguelen plateau option.

All other things being equal? The 'continent world' would be more attractive place to settle by reason of climate and agriculture. But if on the other hand *continent world* was relatively poor in mineral resources but *Kerguelen world* was relatively rich in mineral resources and well endowed with deposits rare or base metals and say large reserves of coal? It might well end with a far larger population by virtue of these additional resources.

EDIT: In answer to the the part of your question about why the North American continent received vastly more colonists than Australia? The reasons, which are all interrelated are, in no particular order (A) The Americas were far, far closer to Europe than Australia is and hence easier and less dangerous/expensive to reach given the technology of the time. (B)They were discovered much earlier. (C) North America in particular far more closely resembled Europe in terms of both climate and it's agricultural potential than Australia did. (Australia' heartlands are for the most part vastly more arid and less productive than than those of North America (D) Its mineral resources and wealth particularly gold and silver were readily apparent and already being exploited by the indigenous inhabitants whereas Australia's equally valuable mineral deposits took a century or so to discover and start exploiting in quantity. (E) Australia's distance from European markets made it more expensive to ship raw materials there.

Answer (score 0):

Either option is certainly imaginable.

I'd argue, as an armchair geologician, that option 1's Kerguelenlandia would not be appreciably warmer *there* than it is *here*. And the reason is that pesky Circumpolar Current. Keeps everything down that way, even lands that do jut into the "temperate" zone, and there aren't very many, far too chilly for comfort.  I suspect that Kerguelenlandia will be cool in the north, probably much cooler than southern Kiwistan, and southern Kerguelenlandia will be Icelandic or worse.

Your second option I think might be better. If the ASBs just did a proper Magellanica, rather than a tiny Antarctica, we could dispense with the Circumpolar Current and Kerguellenlandia (formerly Los Romeros) would be more temperate.

Either way, as for who would get it, I'd imagine that the Dutch and Portuguese might try, but Britain I'm sure would give its left nut for a large resource rich land that didn't have a bajillion poisonous species of everything (Australia) or Natives (Australia & Kiwistan). Forests are good for ship building. I'd imagine land in that zone would be as good for sheep as the other British territories. It's a little off the beaten path, but if you posit a sufficiently resource wealthy country, then it would make an ideal southern arc between South Africa and Australia.

If it ends up connected to Antarctica proper, then things become interesting in the 20th century when other countries want to start exploring!

Due to its distance from Asia, things would also become interesting in the 20th century when WWII begins to loom large. Keep in mind that Imperial Japan's maximum zone of control came very close to the Australian coast, and they did in fact attack many cities and places along the northern coastal regions. Kerguelenlandia would surely become an extremely important location during WWII.

An interesting knock-on consideration: it is possible that if Kerguelenlandia were settled & colonised during the 19th century, and became even moderately industrialised, it could very well have diminished Hong Kong's place as a manufacturing powerhouse: why would the Empire bother with investing in a couple tiny islands when they have bloody rich, bloody big continent that is not filled with squillions of poisonous leaping rats and venomous spiders out the yingyang?

[image]

Comment: My conjecture on slightly warmer temperatures in Alt-Kerguelen mainly concerned its hypothesized northernmost extent in the lower 40s South; the region that is today's Kerguelen at 49 South, I agree would be pretty cold even in summer due to the current. Of course, temperatures like Europe in the 40s North are out of the question in summer anywhere on either model landmass. I prefer the subaerial Kerguelen model as it stretches geology the least, even though it is more difficult to make work. I still wonder whether either of these scenarios could achieve a population above Australia's 25 mil.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that both landmasses lie along the Brouwer and later Clipper ship route to the Indies and Australia, and as such would be a viable station for some form of resupply until the opening of the Suez canal.

Comment: There would almost certainly be natives. Madagascar was colonized from people sailing west from Indonesia between 500 B.C and 200 C.E. They would have hit Alt-Kerguelen before they reached Madagascar. The only places that seem to have had no native populations by the time Europeans started exploring and setting up colonies everywhere are places that are otherwise very difficult to settle like the Galapagos, Saint Helena, Falklands, or the IRL Kerguelen Islands. A larger, more biodiverse Kerguelen would look more like Madagascar or New Zealand in this regard.

Comment: Another knock-on effect if Alt-Kerguelen disrupted the circumpolar current is that we probably would never have had an ice age and Antarctica might be inhabitable. Antarctica only completely froze over because of the current, and that in turn drove the onset of the Pleistocene ice ages. Although Antarctica had glaciers before sub-polar ecosystems with trees are known as late as the Miocene. If you disrupt the formation of the current then parts of Antarctica (esp. the peninsula) would probably still have woody vegetation and terrestrial animals.

Comment: @user2352714 The circumpolar current would almost certainly not be disrupted by the elevated Kerguelen Plateau as it already is deflected by it below the water IRL due to its shallowness. Even the larger continent I proposed tapers off in the mid 50s south- around the same latitude as the Tierra del Fuego and still over 1000 km north of Antarctica. So Antarctica will remain glaciated even if there were changes to more northerly Indian ocean circulation.

Comment: @user2352714 Also the migration to Madagascar was a lot more recent than you think, no earlier than AD 500. Migration to Madagascar was partially connected with the Srivijaya Empire and pre-existing trading routes across the tropical Indian Ocean. The journey even to Alt-Kerguelen from Madagascar is over 2000 km across open water, leading them into some of the coldest and roughest seas in the planet. The Polynesians would not have arrived there. The furthest south they got IRL was New Zealand which isn't as far away from other islands as Kerguelen, and isn't in as rough seas.

Comment: I would agree that natives are likely, but also that it wouldn't be implausible for it to not have natives. Do what works in your story!

Comment: @user2352714 -- I don't think the Proto-Malagasy would have gotten that far south on their way to Madagascar.  Kerguelen --- even a larger continental Kerguelen --- is a very long way south! Not impossible. I've read that it's just possible that the Maori reached as far as the pack ice of Antarctica, or possibly one of the Antarctic islands south of NZ, or possibly even the mainland itself: [Ui-te-Rangiora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ui-te-Rangiora). Realising it was too bloody cold down there, he went home and became a legend.

Comment: @Antarctica07 There's some evidence of potentially older arrivals of humans in Madagascar. 500 CE seems to be considered the upper bound of arrival. Not sure about following pre-existing trade routes, mtDNA suggests a very small initial population rather than extensive gene flow. The bigger issue is Madagascar is straight west from Indonesia over open ocean. The distance between IRL Kerguelen and Indonesia is only 100 km greater than Indonesia to Madagascar. If people can find Madagascar from Indonesia, it isn't too much of a stretch to think they could find Kerguelen.

Comment: @elemtilas Subpolar landmasses have been known to be colonized in the past if they are large enough, Iceland and Greenland come to mind. It people aren't on an island it doesn't necessarily mean no one ever saw it, just that no one established a long-term settlement before that. If Kerguelen is large enough here to support its own unique biota and be worth colonizing, I wouldn't be surprised if the Maori or Srivijaya pulled a "southern Vikings" and colonized it.

Comment: @user2352714 -- Not saying it *can't* be colonised, only that Kerguelenlandia would be waaaay out of the way for folks [travelling west out of Indonesia](https://www.quora.com/How-did-the-Malagasy-people-manage-to-sail-from-Borneo-and-colonise-Madagascar). Nice thing about the Indonesia to Madagascar route is you've got a nice current taking straight to your destination. Kerguelen is well within the Circumpolar Current.

Comment: @user2352714 1. They don't have to be large. The Faroes have a similar climate to some places like Ile de Amsterdam or the Crozet Islands, and the Faroes were indeed settled by the Vikings despite being smaller than Kerguelen. So maybe the distinction here has little to do with size and more to do with the fact that one is a short hop off of Norway, and the Vikings are well suited to the land, and the other (Kerguelen) is 2000+ km out at sea and the Polynesians are from the tropics. At any rate, my question statement in the body of the text states that I am asking about European settlement.

Comment: @Antarctica07 If there are natives that's going to affect your plot. The Europeans are going to be more likely to settle there if there's already a native culture, because the presence of local trade and labor will make a colony easier to set up. It will also make the Kerguelens more likely to want independence and hence become a post-colonial nation.

Comment: @user2352714 I don't know what to say other than that I believe it is astronomically unlikely for there to be Polynesian settlers in this place, and that furthermore, my question specifically addresses European colonization and makes no mention of any indigenous people because I never intended for there to be any, as such, further discussion as to their presence on this landmass is not in service of answering the question I did pose, namely how successful and populous a European colony in such a setting could become.